# jQuery javascript binding and calling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function named 'mc_change'. Also, I have a textbox whose change event should call that JavaScript function

> <input type="text" id="mc_val" onchange="javascript:mc_change();" />

It's not working
Can anyone suggest me same normal JavaScript or jQuery?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example script is perfectly valid - there are no obvious errors in what you've provided.

Using 'normal' JavaScript you can attach the event with:

```
document.getElementById('mc_val').onchange = mc_change;
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('#mc_val').change(mc_change);
```

Of course, there is no reason to believe this will fix the problem, since they should all be (more or less) equivalent to your example. "It's not working" doesn't really help.

Comment: Neither of these is correct, you're calling the function immediately in both cases, not assigning the function as a handler...it should not have parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, your script is valid, and should do what is intended.  However, I am guessing that the event you want is probably not the onchange event.  In my dealings with text input, I've found that binding to onchange will only do something when focus is lifted from the text input, so using a combination of events to cover several methods of input might be your best bet.

The following is an example of the events I generally use to do something when the text changes:

```
$('#mc_val').bind({
   change : mc_change,
   keydown : mc_change,  // for key presses
   mouseup : mc_change,  // for mouse paste
   mousemove : mc_change // for mouse paste
});
```

Comment: +1 - You can also just use space separated events in this case, for example: `$('#mc_val').bind('change keyup paste', mc_change);`

Comment: Nice one, I haven't seen that syntax before.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

remove the 'javascript:'... it should be:

`<input type="text" id="mc_val" onchange="mc_change();" />`

Comment: the `javascript:` is redundant, but it isn't incorrect. Shouldn't make a difference.